# How to recreate btmp file in ubuntu server?

Tags: server

While clearing out some logs, I deleted the file `btmp` located at `/var/log/btmp` in my ubuntu server.

Will it cause any issues? How can I recreate this file so that new bad login attempts get logged in?

Thank you.

Comment: syslogd should regenerate the file automatically when the first bad login attempt occurs. Open up a TTY, do a test bad login, and check if the file was re-created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If will be re-created automatically. Everything in `/var/log/` will.

However if you want to this is how it needs to look:

```
ls -ltr btmp
 -rw-rw---- 1 root utmp 0 sep  1 00:00 btmp
```

so ...

```
sudo -i
cd /var/log/
touch btmp
chown root:utmp btmp
chmod 660 btmp
```

You are better off using `rm *[0-9] *.gz` and then use `> {file}` if you need to clean up space in `/var/log/`. That last one empties a file but leaves it on the system with the permissions it already has.

Comment: Thank you. What does root:utmp mean?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. It means the file will be owned by root of group utmp. is that correct?

Comment: yes it does and the chmod does the "read write" part for user and group